# What does it indicate when the Train and Test lines run in parallel?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, curve-fitting, supervised-learning

In the Model Accuracy plot of my NN model, the Train and Test shows a steep curve upto 50 epochs after which those run parallel upto 1500 epochs. Is it correct that bifurcation at a point signifies that the model is getting over fitted beyond that point? If so, then my model has no bifurcation point up to 1500 epochs. I didn't try for more than 1500 epochs. Should I test for more epochs for getting a bifurcation point or conclude that the model is perfect? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model fitting stagnates after 50 epochs, you will likely not see a big change by extending the epochs beyond 1500, at least not without reducing the learning rate of your optimizer after those ~50 epochs. Since they're both parallel, that does indeed imply that the model is not overfitting. Models are rarely perfect, the better question is does it serve the purpose it's intended to serve? If you would like better results, then you might want to explore adding additional parameters or layers and see if you can gain test accuracy, maybe try to find the point where it starts to overfit and then adjust accordingly to avoid the overfitting while still getting better test results.